# Python3 string and hmac auth

Tags: string, file, python-3.x

I made a pice of code that works, where they key and secret are declared in the code such:

```
key = 'ewjewej2j020e2'
secret = 'dw8d8d8ddh8h8hfehf0fh'
```

Then do my business and works. But if i put key and secret in an external file in two lines separated by a newline carrier and load it up:

```
file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../keys')
f = open(file, 'r')
key = f.read()
secret = f.read()
f.close()
```

I get an auth error, as no token provided because I'm sure something fishy happened with encoding of key and secret.

Ok, if all strings in Python3 are Unicode, then why loading from file the script does not work and declaring inside the code does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`read()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) will read the entire file. Try with `readline()`.

```
with open('keys', 'r') as f:
    key = f.readline().rstrip()
    secret = f.readline().rstrip()
print(key)
print(secret)
# ewjewej2j020e2 
# dw8d8d8ddh8h8hfehf0fh
```

or splitting read:

```
with open('keys', 'r') as f:
    key, secret = f.read().split()
print(key)
print(secret)
# ewjewej2j020e2 
# dw8d8d8ddh8h8hfehf0fh
```

---

```
with open('keys', 'r') as f:
    key, secret = map(str.rstrip, f)
print(key)
print(secret)
# ewjewej2j020e2 
# dw8d8d8ddh8h8hfehf0fh
```